# Why do I need separable compilation?

Tags: cmake, cuda

I have the code shown below. As far as I understood, separable compilation must be turned on when

1. CUDA device code is separated into .h and .cu files
2. Use ObjectA's device code into Object's B device code

however, in my main function I am not having any of the cases above. Could you tell me why do I have to set separable compilation for this sample project?

**BitHelper.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

#define COMPILE_TARGET __host__ __device__

class BitHelper
{
public:
    COMPILE_TARGET BitHelper();
    COMPILE_TARGET ~BitHelper();

    COMPILE_TARGET static void clear(unsigned int& val0);
};
```

**BitHelper.cu**

```
#include "bithelper.h"

BitHelper::BitHelper()
{}

BitHelper::~BitHelper()
{}

void BitHelper::clear(unsigned int& val0)
{
    val0 = 0x0000;
}
```

**Consume_BitHelper.h**

```
#pragma once

class Consume_BitHelper
{
public:
    void apply();

private:
    bool test_cpu();
    bool test_gpu();
};
```

**Consume_BitHelper.cu**

```
#include "consume_bithelper.h"

#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "bithelper.h"

__global__
void myKernel()
{
    unsigned int FLAG_VALUE = 0x2222;
    printf("GPU before: %d\n", FLAG_VALUE);
    BitHelper::clear(FLAG_VALUE);
    printf("GPU after: %d\n", FLAG_VALUE);
}

void Consume_BitHelper::apply()
{
    test_cpu();
    test_gpu();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}

bool Consume_BitHelper::test_cpu()
{
    std::cout << "TEST CPU" << std::endl;
    unsigned int FLAG_VALUE = 0x1111;
    std::cout << "CPU before: " << FLAG_VALUE << std::endl;
    BitHelper::clear(FLAG_VALUE);
    std::cout << "CPU after : " << FLAG_VALUE << std::endl;
    return true;
}

bool Consume_BitHelper::test_gpu()
{
    std::cout << "TEST GPU" << std::endl;
    myKernel << <1, 1 >> > ();
    return true;
}
```

**main.cu**

```
#include "consume_bithelper.h"
#include "bithelper.h"

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Consume_BitHelper cbh;
    cbh.apply();

    std::cout << "\nPress any key to continue...";
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(cuda_class LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

#BitHelper needs separable compilation because we have separated declaration from definition
add_library(bithelper_lib STATIC bithelper.cu)
set_property(TARGET bithelper_lib PROPERTY CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

#Consume_BitHelper needs separable compilation because we call BitHelper's device code
#from Consume_BitHelper's kernel
add_library(consume_bithelper_lib STATIC consume_bithelper.cu)
set_property(TARGET consume_bithelper_lib PROPERTY CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
target_link_libraries(consume_bithelper_lib bithelper_lib)

#We only call CPU code so no need of separable compilation?
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cu)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} bithelper_lib consume_bithelper_lib)
```

The errors I'm getting are these [image]

**EDIT**

According to *Robert Crovella*'s post `Consume_BitHelper.cu` uses `BitHelper::clear` defined in a *separate compilation unit*.

1. Does it mean I have to activate **only** separate compilation for `BitHelper`?

Since separate compilation has to do only with device code called from device code.

2. Why am I getting the mentioned errors when separate compilation is NOT on for cuda_class? (which is the executable created from CMake and is not calling any device code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separable compilation has to do with how the compiler handles function calls. In exchange for a little bit of overhead, you get the ability to make true function calls and thus access code from other "compilation units" (i.e. .cu source files).

As GPU programmers are obsessed with performance (particularly the extra registers that get used when separable compilation is enabled) Nvidia made it an option instead of default.

You should only need separable compilation for .cu files that access functions/globals defined in other .cu files.